# Eclipse4: Load a Part but don't show it

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm getting a reference to my `Part` via:

```
    @Inject private EPartService partService;
    MPart clientPart = partService.findPart("parts.clientpart");
```

How can I load that part now so that it's

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void createComposite(Composite parent)
```

function gets called?

I've been trying

```
partService.createPart("parts.clientpart");
```

Didn't actually create the desired Part. I guess it just returned a new instance.

```
partService.activate(clientPart);
```

This loaded the Part but **also** showed it which I don't want.

How can I load a `Part` so that it's `@PostConstruct` is called and the `Part` is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
partService.showPart(id, PartState.CREATE);
```

the part needs to have `To be rendered` off in the application.e4xmi